# express res.download returns data instead of file, and browser doesn't prompt download window

Tags: node.js, express

I have a file (myFIle.apk) at the same level of my app.js file.

In my app.js I have the following code :

```
app.get("/downloadFile",(req,res)=> {
    res.download("myFile.apk", function(error){
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error : ", error);
        } else {
            console.log("ok");
        }      
    });
});
```

When I call the route from the front, the browser does not display a prompt windows and the response is something like :

```
data: 'PK\x03\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006Vx�H+\x00\x00��\\x13\... erfaces.propertiesUT\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\f\x05\fC�\x03\x00\x00�a\x06\x00\x00', status: 200, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Comment: `When I call the route from the front` - How are you calling it? I assume you are submitting a form?

Comment: just by using an axios.get("myUrl"), do I need a form submission ?
@slebetman

Comment: Not sure how axios handles it behind the scenes but if it uses the fetch API then the browser will not display a download prompt because by using the fetch API you are telling the browser you want API level access to the http request and so don't perform any default behaviour because you will handle all behaviours in your code.